# LEFT JOIN not showing counts 0 the way I expected

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

TABLE A

| CrimeType | CrimeSubType | Neighborhood | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Jeff Park | 2024 |
| 2 | 2 | Cong Park | 2023 |
| 2 | 2 | Cong Park | 2024 |
| 2 | 2 | Jeff Park | 2024 |
| 3 | 1 | Jeff Park | 2024 |
| 3 | 2 | Jeff Park | 2023 |
| 3 | 1 | Jeff Park | 2023 |

I then have a second table that defines the crime types as a human readable category

TABLE B

| CrimeType | CrimeSubType | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | VIOLENT CRIME |
| 1 | 2 | VIOLENT CRIME |
| 2 | 1 | VIOLENT CRIME |
| 2 | 2 | PROPERTY CRIME |
| 3 | 1 | PROPERTY CRIME |
| 3 | 2 | DRUG CRIME |

I would like the output of my postgres (if possible) to display results such as the one below (assuming year for 2024)

| Neighborhood | Category | Counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jeff Park | VIOLENT CRIME | 0 |
| Cong Park | VIOLENT CRIME | 1 |
| Jeff Park | PROPERTY CRIME | 3 |
| Cong Park | PROPERTY CRIME | 2 |
| Jeff Park | DRUG CRIME | 1 |
| Cong Park | DRUG CRIME | 0 |

I was able to get it to look like the above using something like the following:

```sql
SELECT
  Neighborhood,
  Category,
  COUNT(Neighborhood)
from A
INNER JOIN B
   ON (b.CrimeType = 
a.crimeType
  AND B.CrimeSubType = b.CrimeSubType
  AND a.year = 2024
GROUP BY
  Neighborhood,
  Category
```

I looked up some answers and it said to change the INNER JOIN to a left or right join. (I believe in my case it would be a right join?) However, I feel my case is too complex and I am missing something.

```sql
SELECT
  Neighborhood,
  Category,
  COUNT(Neighborhood)
from A
LEFT JOIN B
   ON (b.CrimeType = a.crimeType
  AND B.CrimeSubType = b.CrimeSubType
  AND a.year = 2024
GROUP BY
  Neighborhood,
  Category
```

Still does not work, it will display some nulls but not the way I intended it, what am I missing?

Comment: `but not the way I intended it` ... what is your desired output?  Do you have separate tables having all neighborhoods and categories?

Comment: my desired output is the third table, for example I would like for anytime a neighborhood does not have a VIOLENT CRIME it shows a count of 0. I tried a LEFT JOIN and instead I get nulls for neighborhood and category, and count of like 37 (I am assuming its counting the rows that don't match to the respective category)

Comment: The counts in your displayed result seem to disagree with the given sample data. Either way, the currently accepted answer doesn't seem right (besides being ineffiicent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rightfully, there should be bona fide tables containing all categories and neighborhoods.  In the absence of that, we can use subqueries to find them, then left join as you were already doing:

```sql
SELECT n.Neighborhood, c.Category, COUNT(b.CrimeType) AS Counts
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Neighborhood FROM A) n
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM B) c
LEFT JOIN A a
    ON a.Neighborhood = n.Neighborhood AND
       a.year = 2024
LEFT JOIN B b
    ON B b.Category = c.Category AND
         b.CrimeType = a.CrimeType AND
         b.CrimeSubType = b.CrimeSubType
GROUP BY
    n.Neighborhood,
    c.Category
ORDER BY
    n.Neighborhood,
    c.Category;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I spent roughly half the day trying to solve this, and this solution solved the issue. I believe I was missing the CROSS JOIN

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (all of this should be specified in the question):

- Table `B` is the list of crime types, `(CrimeType, CrimeSubType)` being its PK.
- You want to group by `Category`, lumping multiple crime types together (exactly two for category in the sample data).
- You want to display the full grid (Cartesian Product) of distinct values in `Neighborhood` and `Category`, along with the sum of all cases in table `A` for the given year (2024 in the example).
- Sort descending by `Category` and `Neighborhood` (like your displayed result suggests).

This should be the most efficient query:

```sql
SELECT n.neighborhood, b.category, COALESCE(sum(a.ct), 0) AS counts
FROM   b
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT neighborhood FROM a) n
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT crimetype, crimesubtype, neighborhood, count(neighborhood) AS ct
   FROM   a
   WHERE  year = 2024
   GROUP  BY crimetype, crimesubtype, neighborhood
   ) a  USING (crimetype, crimesubtype, neighborhood)
GROUP  BY b.category, n.neighborhood
ORDER  BY b.category DESC, n.neighborhood DESC;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qNEXpYaL)

Aside: Avoid CaMeL-case identifiers in Postgres if you can. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Answer (score 0):

You would need a left join if there are un-categorised combinations of crimeType+CrimeSubType, and to avoid NULLs in the output you can used coalesce as follows:

```
SELECT
       Neighborhood
    , coalesce(b.Category,'Un-categorised') as Category
    , COUNT(*) as count_of
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON b.CrimeType = a.crimeType
    AND B.CrimeSubType = b.CrimeSubType
WHERE a.year = 2024
GROUP BY 
       Neighborhood
    , coalesce(Category,'Un-categorised')
```

nb: a.year = 2024 should be applied as a where clause (not part of the ON conditions for table b)

Comment: Your answer will filter off categories/neighborhoods which don't have data for 2024.

Comment: Yes it will, but I didn't see the desire for all neighborhoods  to be listed stated in the requirements. Plus I was guessing there may be (CrimeType, CrimeSubType) combinations that are not categorised - so that was the focus.